# Spark Session read mulitple files instead of using pattern

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to read couple of CSV files using `SparkSession` from a folder on HDFS ( i.e I don't want to read all the files in the folder )

I get the following error while running (code at the end):

```
Path does not exist:
file:/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_2.csv,
/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_1.csv
```

I don't want to use the pattern while reading, like `/home/temp/*.csv`, reason being in future I have logic to pick only one or two files in the folder out of 100 CSV files

Please advise

```
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName(SparkCSVProcessors.class.getName())
            .master(master).getOrCreate();
    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel("ERROR");

    Set<String> fileSet = Files.list(Paths.get("/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/"))
            .filter(name -> name.toString().endsWith(".csv"))
            .map(name -> name.toString())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();

    Dataset<Row> rawDataset = sparkSession.read()
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("delimiter", ",")
            //.load(String.join(" , ", fileSet));
            .load("/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_2.csv, " +
                    "/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_1.csv");
```

**UPDATE**

I can iterate the files and do an union as below. Please recommend if there is a better way ...

```
    Dataset<Row> unifiedDataset = null;

    for (String fileName : fileSet) {
        Dataset<Row> tempDataset = sparkSession.read()
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true")
                .format("csv")
                .option("delimiter", ",")
                .load(fileName);
        if (unifiedDataset != null) {
            unifiedDataset= unifiedDataset.unionAll(tempDataset);
        } else {
            unifiedDataset = tempDataset;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be about hdfs and local path. When you are using it in local mode, it will try to read the files from your local filesystem, when you use it in a Server, it will try to read from hdfs. The solution will depend on how you are running and where the files are located, in test and in server environments.

Comment: I believe when we give spark read a set of value it accepts only "DIRECTORIES" and not individual files. Does the behavior change when in HDFS mode vs local file mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a String with the value:

> "/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_2.csv,
>   /home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_1.csv"

Instead passing two filenames as parameters, which should be done by:

```
.load("/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_2.csv",
"/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_1.csv");
```

The **comma** has to be outside the strin and you should have two values, instead of one String.

Comment: Hi @dirceusemighini how to use this path as regex. Path does not exist error comes when empty path or file. how to respolve that. This is the format of regex I have used "dbfs:/mnt/tests/*/2020/04/{01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08}/*/*/*.json,/mnt/tests/*/2020/03/{25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}/*/*/*.json"

Comment: Hi @SajithVijesekara, it seems that you are commiting the same mistake described at the question. You should split each folder entrance at a different string  "dbfs:/mnt/tests/*/2020/04/{01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08}/*/*/*.json","/mnt/tests/*/2020/03/{25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}/*/*/*.json" -> you missed the " after json and before /mnt... By the way, it's not a good practice to use mount points to access data, it's better to access this folders using it's access keys, which should be stored at a key storage system (keyvault if you are in azure)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to read multiple files from HDFS without using regex like "/path/*.csv". what you are missing is each path needs to be separately with quotes and separated by ","

You can read using code as below, ensure that you have added SPARK CSV library :

```
sqlContext.read.format("csv").load("/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_1.csv","/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_2.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern can be helpful as well.
You want to select two files at time.
If they are sequencial then you could do something like

```
.load("/home/cloudera/works/JavaKafkaSparkStream/input/input_[1-2].csv")
```

if more files then just do **input_[1-5].csv**